# Sonar 2.12 unable to read and import source file

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm trying to run Sonar 2.12 with Ant runner. Not using maven,But sonar target fails with an exception

```
Unable to read and import the source file : 'D:\JUnitDocletPoC\iLog_Client\src\
ava\com\junitTest\NameFinder.java' with the charset : 'UTF-8'.

at
 at org.sonar.plugins.squid.JavaSourceImporter.importSource(JavaSourceImporter,java.)
at  at org.sonar.plugins.squid.JavaSourceImporter.parseDirs(JavaSourceImporter,java)
 at org.sonar.plugins.squid.JavaSourceImporter.analyse(JavaSourceImporter.java)
 at org.sonar.plugins.squid.JavaSourceImporter.analyse(JavaSourceImporter.java)
```

This fails at all the java source files and charsets and not specific to any file/charset.
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the [sonar.sourceEncoding](http://sonar.sourceEncoding) parameter to UTF-8? If not, try setting it to Cp1252.

Cp1252 is the default encoding on windows machines. Unfortunately it's not completely compatible with UTF-8 (the default for most Java installations). Some windows based editors will write incompatible characters that trigger this kind of Java read error.

One common offender is the "£" symbol, which is part of the extended ascii character set. It therefore should be written as a two byte character under UTF-8 :-(

Comment: I tried to set this value to UTF-8 as well as Cp1252 with the

Comment: Sounds like you might have a mixture of file encodings.... To rule it out, I suggest you analyse each file and verify it's encoding. The most likely explanation is that you have a file with something like a "£" symbol written incorrectly (Happened to me once and spent a lot of time finding it... Small problem, big time waster)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while running sonar-runner.By looking logs i found root cause of the issue as "Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segmen
t ITBASONAR.SYS_LOB0000289347C00003$$ by 128 in tablespace USERS". Well i simply increased size of tablespace USERS bu 1024 and everything worked fine.